# Decorator Pattern Piano Application

Tags: java, javafx, decorator

I'm trying to apply the Decorator pattern but so far I'm having troubles getting it to work the way I want.

Basically I'm trying to create a piano application which has a piano key super class that extends the JavaFX rectangle and two subclasses white key and black key both of which have implementations for methods when you hover over them.

They work fine but I'm now trying to create Decorator classes that will override the superclass' play method by providing its own play method and appending the relevant string for the audio file for that decorator.
e.g. PianoKeyViolinDecorator will append "violin" to the end of the audio file name before it plays it.

The play method works but the methods for hovering over the rectangle don't work. And unless I set a height and width in the Decorator the rectangle won't show up in my GUI. Is there any way to get the rectangle of the piano key to show up without having to recreate a new rectangle in the Decorator class?

Here is my decorator class:

```
public class PianoKeyDecorator extends KeyView {

private KeyView keyView;

public PianoKeyDecorator(KeyView keyView) {
    this.keyView = keyView;
}

public void lightOn() {
    keyView.lightOn();
}

public void lightOff() {
    keyView.lightOff();
}

@Override
public void play() {
    AudioClip audioFile = new AudioClip(AssignmentTemplate.class.getResource(keyView.keyAudioSource() + "_violin.wav").toExternalForm());
    audioFile.play();
}
```

And my Superclass

```
public abstract class KeyView extends Rectangle {

private AudioClip keyAudio;
private String keyAudioSource;
private String keyId;
private String background;
private String backgroundHover;

public KeyView(double width, double height, String keyAudioSource, String keyText, String background, String backgroundHover) {
    this.keyAudioSource = keyAudioSource;
    keyAudio = new AudioClip(AssignmentTemplate.class.getResource(keyAudioSource + ".wav").toExternalForm());
    this.background = AssignmentTemplate.class.getResource("resources/"+ background).toExternalForm();
    this.backgroundHover = AssignmentTemplate.class.getResource("resources/"+ backgroundHover).toExternalForm();
    this.getStyleClass().add("key");
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
}

public KeyView(){}

public void play() {
    keyAudio.play();
}

public void setAudioClip(AudioClip keyAudio) {
    this.keyAudio = keyAudio; 
}

public abstract void lightOn();
public abstract void lightOff();    

public void setKeyId(String keyId) {
    this.keyId = keyId;
}

public String getKeyId() {
    return keyId;
}

public String getBackground() {
    return background;
}

public String getBackgroundHover() {
    return backgroundHover;
}

public String keyAudioSource() {
    return keyAudioSource;
}
```

Here is one of my subclasses

public class BlackKeyView extends KeyView {

```
public SharpKeyView(String keyAudioFile, String keyText, String background, String backgroundHover) {
        super(64, 170, keyAudioFile, keyText, background, backgroundHover);
        setKeyId("sharp" + keyText);
}

public void lightOn() {
    super.setFill(Color.BLUE);
}

public void lightOff() {
    super.setFill(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to bind all relevant properties of your decorator to the underlying object:

```
public PianoKeyDecorator(KeyView keyView) {
    this.keyView = keyView;
    fillProperty().bindBidirectional(keyView.fillProperty()); 
    // bind any other properties you wish to change. 
}
```

a different approach might be to completely separate the view part of your keys from their logic, but that would presumably force you to change your design quite a bit.

*Edit:*
Come to think of it, I think for this example the [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern might fit much better than decorator, and so you'll only change the way the sound is played instead of the whole key.